# NMinimize stops with no more memory?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am using NMinimize function for simulation based optimization. So my objective function is a simulation that runs for every combination of variable values evaluated by NMinimize function. However, the problem I have is the Nminimize function ceases after the first run (I am printing the time stamp for every iteration) and eventually after a long time gives me out of memory error. I even tried with different methods such as "RandomSearch" and "SimulatedAnnealing" with custom method parameter values, but in vain. Can some one pinpoint where I am going wrong?

edit: My code is long, but as requested is given below:

```
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Module[{b1 = a1, b2 = a2, b3 = a3, L = 3, Flen = 1, Rlen = 1,SimTime = 60, Kj = 150,w = 20,Theta = 5, dt = 6,delta = 1,DemandDuration = 10,RMstart = 1,RMLocation = 3, TT = 0}, 

Print[DateString[]]; Vf = Theta w; dx = Vf dt/3600; capacity = w*Vf*Kj/(Vf + w);n = Round[Flen/dx];m = Round[SimTime/dt];p = Round[Rlen/dx];Rdensity = Table[0*i, {i, p}, {i, m}, {i, n}];Rflow = Table[0*i, {i, p}, {i, m}, {i, n}];Fdensity = Table[0*i, {i, n}, {i, m}];Fflow = Table[0*i, {i, n}, {i, m}];demand[n_, k_] := Min[k*Vf, n*capacity];supply[n_, k_] := Min[(n*Kj - k)*w, n*capacity];flo[demand_, supply_] := Min[demand, supply];den[k_, qin_, qout_] := k + (qin - qout)/Vf;
merge[n_, Fu_, Fd_, Rd_] := Min[1, supply[n, Fd]/(demand[n, Fu] + 0.01)]*demand[1, Rd]/delta;Nsupply[n_, k_, qsum_] := Min[(n*Kj - k)*Vf - qsum, n*capacity];
RM[x_, t_] := N[b1 x^2 + b2 x + b3];alpha[a_] := 1500*a/Flen;beta[a_] := 0.1*a/Flen;

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, 
For[i = 1, i <= p, i++, Rdensity[[i, 1, k]] = 0;];
For[j = 1, j <= DemandDuration, j++, Rdensity[[p, j, k]] = alpha[n*dx]*delta/Vf;
TT = TT + Rdensity[[p, j, k]]];];

For[j = 1, j <= 4, j++, 
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, 
If[k == 1, 
  Rflow[[1, j, k]] = 
   merge[L, Fdensity[[k, j]], Fdensity[[k, j]], 
    Rdensity[[1, j, k]]], 
  Rflow[[1, j, k]] = 
   merge[L, Fdensity[[k, j]], Fdensity[[k - 1, j]], 
    Rdensity[[1, j, k]]]];
 If[k == 1, 
  Fflow[[k, j]] = 
   flo[demand[L, Fdensity[[k, j]]], supply[L, Fdensity[[k, j]]]], 
  Fflow[[k, j]] = 
   flo[demand[L, Fdensity[[k, j]]], 
    supply[L, Fdensity[[k - 1, j]]] - Rflow[[1, j, k - 1]]*dx]];
 If[k > 1 && j < m, 
  Fdensity[[k - 1, j + 1]] = 
   den[Fdensity[[k - 1, 
     j]], (Rflow[[1, j, k - 1]] - beta[(n)*dx]*Fflow[[k, j]])*dx +
      Fflow[[k, j]], Fflow[[k - 1, j]]];
  TT = TT + Fdensity[[k - 1, j + 1]];];
 If[k == n && j < m, 
  Fdensity[[k, j + 1]] = 
   den[Fdensity[[k, j]], Rflow[[1, j, k]]*dx, Fflow[[k, j]]];
  TT = TT + Fdensity[[k, j + 1]];];
 For[i = 2, i <= p, i++, 
  If[i == RMLocation && j >= RMstart, 
   Rflow[[i, j, k]] = 
    Min[RM[k dx, j dt], 
     flo[demand[1, Rdensity[[i, j, k]]], 
      supply[1, Rdensity[[i - 1, j, k]]]]], 
   Rflow[[i, j, k]] = 
    flo[demand[1, Rdensity[[i, j, k]]], 
     supply[1, Rdensity[[i - 1, j, k]]]]];
  If[j < m, 
   Rdensity[[i - 1, j + 1, k]] = 
    den[Rdensity[[i - 1, j, k]], Rflow[[i, j, k]], 
     Rflow[[i - 1, j, k]]];
   TT = TT + Rdensity[[i - 1, j + 1, k]];]];];];
For[j = 5, j <= m, j++, 
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, 
If[k == 1, 
 Rflow[[1, j, k]] = 
  merge[L, Fdensity[[k, j]], Fdensity[[k, j]], 
   Rdensity[[1, j, k]]], 
 Rflow[[1, j, k]] = 
  merge[L, Fdensity[[k, j]], Fdensity[[k - 1, j]], 
   Rdensity[[1, j, k]]]];
FQsum = 0;
For[r = 1, r <= Theta - 1, r++, FQsum = FQsum + Fflow[[k, j - r]]];
If[k == 1, 
 Fflow[[k, j]] = 
  flo[demand[L, Fdensity[[k, j]]], supply[L, Fdensity[[k, j]]]], 
 Fflow[[k, j]] = 
  flo[demand[L, Fdensity[[k, j]]], 
   Nsupply[L, Fdensity[[k - 1, j - Theta + 1]], FQsum] - 
    Rflow[[1, j, k - 1]]*dx]];
If[k > 1 && j < m, 
 Fdensity[[k - 1, j + 1]] = 
  den[Fdensity[[k - 1, 
    j]], (Rflow[[1, j, k - 1]] - beta[(n)*dx]*Fflow[[k, j]])*dx + 
    Fflow[[k, j]], Fflow[[k - 1, j]]];
 TT = TT + Fdensity[[k - 1, j + 1]];];
If[k == n && j < m, 
 Fdensity[[k, j + 1]] = 
  den[Fdensity[[k, j]], Rflow[[1, j, k]]*dx, Fflow[[k, j]]];
 TT = TT + Fdensity[[k, j + 1]];];
For[i = 2, i <= p, i++, RQsum = 0;
 For[r = 1, r <= Theta - 1, r++, 
  RQsum = RQsum + Rflow[[i, j - r, k]]];
 If[i == RMLocation && j >= RMstart, 
  Rflow[[i, j, k]] = 
   Min[RM[k dx, j dt], 
    flo[demand[1, Rdensity[[i, j, k]]], 
     Nsupply[1, Rdensity[[i - 1, j - Theta + 1, k]], RQsum]]], 
  Rflow[[i, j, k]] = 
   flo[demand[1, Rdensity[[i, j, k]]], 
    Nsupply[1, Rdensity[[i - 1, j - Theta + 1, k]], RQsum]]];
 If[j < m, 
  Rdensity[[i - 1, j + 1, k]] = 
   den[Rdensity[[i - 1, j, k]], Rflow[[i, j, k]], 
    Rflow[[i - 1, j, k]]];
  TT = TT + Rdensity[[i - 1, j + 1, k]];]];];];

TT]

NMinimize[{f[x, y, z], {x, y,z} \[Element] Integers}, {{x , 27, 30}, {y, 797, 800}, {z, 2497, 2500}}];
```

Ps. Also any suggestions to improve the performance of this code will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Brama, without working code it is neigh impossible to help you. Please provide working code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Does setting `$HistoryLength = 0` help at all?

Comment: $HistoryLength = 0 does not seem to work

Comment: Looking at your code I see a few things I suggest you should change to clean it up. You should not define symbols that start with capital letters as those might shadow Mathematica defined sybolm. Don't have function definitions in your `Module` as you are defining them over and over again when `NMinimize` calls your function possibly thausends of times. You'll also get printed everytime the `DateString`which slows down the code and do you really need to know every time `NMinimize` call your function what time is was? You have twice the statement `If[k==1,` in your code up top is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this for `Reals` instead of `Integers` to see if it solves at all?

Comment: Thanks Matariki for your suggestions. As suggested, I pulled out the variables and functions out of the `Module`. I wanted to print the `DataString` so that I can see if the program is slowing down over generations. `If[k==1,` is needed twice. As you may have tried, the `f[a,b,c]` works fine for any arbitrary values of `a,b,c`, but the `NMinimize` function does not run multiple times as you would anticipate. Also, I tried `Reals` without much luck.

Comment: Use the `EvaluationMonitor` option to print the parameters `f` is called with and when `Nminimize` got stuck use the same parameters to see what your functions returns. I have no access to Mathematica right now and can help therefore only by giving you suggestions. You should update your code in the Question to the latest version you are using. I totally forgot to mention you have to define the parameters to `f` as follows: `f[a1_?NumericQ, ...` to make sure `NMinimize` is calling your code only with numeric values! I guess that's it! Man am I slow today to see that.

Comment: The `EvaluationMonitor` is a great idea and I could see that the `Nminimize` is running iterations. What is a good way to see the value to the objective function during every iteration?

Comment: Brama, are you satisfied with that or is the main issue still not resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to release memory space is redefine functions (Fdensity, Fflow, etc) conveniently in order to reduce the number of excessive functional calls in the execution. Using the Alexey Popkov's routine ("[Profiling memory usage in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418892/profiling-memory-usage-in-mathematica)") we have the following result for the allocated bytes:

```
 - 6739593360    Fdensity
 - 1984112096    Fflow
 - 1679274128    Rdensity
 - 1453549616    Rflow
 - 37327744      FQsum
 - 977560        RQsum
```

Also, it is necessary the use of _?NumericQ restriction in the functions to avoid inconvenient symbolic processing.

Comment: The problem is resolved, but gave rise to a different problem. Can some one look at it? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42980/nminimize-not-working?noredirect=1#comment128642_42980