# About nonstandard evaluation

Tags: evaluation, mathematical-optimization, hold

I'd like to do some tedious calculations. The toy model is something like:

```
n = 3;
phaseList = ToExpression /@ StringTemplate["phase``"] /@ Range[n];

Abs[#]^2 &@
 Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList] /. MapThread[Rule, {phaseList, Range@n}]]
```

The output should be
    (*  {1.44297, 0.33185, 1.22518}  *)

However, when the calculations go more complicated, it would be convenient to do like this,

```
Abs[#]^2 &@
     Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList]]+phaseList/.MapThread[Rule, {phaseList, Range@n}]
```

Now, a warning appears,

> Fourier::fftl: Argument {E^(I phase1),E^(I phase2),E^(I phase3),E^(I
>   phase4),E^(I phase5)} is not a non-empty list or rectangular array of
>   numeric quantities.

so my first question is, how to avoid this warning?

Actually, This complicated calculation would be the formula used in NMinimize,

```
NMinimize[Abs[#]^2 &@
         Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList]]+phaseList,phaseList]
```

To suppress any error, this can be used in this way,according to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42980/nminimize-to-optimize-function-module/43309#43309)

```
NMinimize[Hold@Abs[#]^2 &@
             Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList]]+phaseList,phaseList]
```

But I really cannot figure out how it works.

So my second question is, why the `Hold` here should be presented.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Abs[#]^2 &@list` can be written more succinctly as `Abs@list^2`

Answer (score 4):

First of all I recommend using indexed objects for `phaseList`:

```
phaseList = Array[phase, 3];

Abs[#]^2 &@Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList] /. phase[x_] :> x]
```

> ```
> {1.44297, 0.33185, 1.22518}
> ```

You get the error because [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) is evaluated before `phaseList` expressions are replaced with numeric values, just as the warning message says.  You avoid it by preventing that evaluation, or simply [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) it as it doesn't prevent later evaluation as you intend.

```
Abs[#]^2 &@Hold[Fourier][Exp[I*phaseList]] + phaseList /. 
  phase[x_] :> x // ReleaseHold

Block[{Fourier},
  Abs[#]^2 &@Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList]] + phaseList /. phase[x_] :> x
]

Quiet[
  Abs[#]^2 &@Fourier[Exp[I*phaseList]] + phaseList /. phase[x_] :> x,
  Fourier::fftl
]
```