# function on parts of lists works only in pure function?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, assignment, pure-function

For example, I'd like to take the first four upper left values of a matrix, i.e.

```
f[x_] := f[x] = x[[;; 2, ;; 2]];
```

This works nicely, e.g. `f[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]= {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}`

Now, I was trying to ged rid of the delayed evaluation and just use `f[x_]=...` which doesn't work: `Part::take: Cannot take positions 1 through 2 in x.`

But if I define the function like this, it works:

```
f = #[[;; 2, ;; 2]]&;
```

Why is this? And how would I do it in the `f[x_]=`pattern?

Of course, I could just use delayed evaluation but in another case I have a more complicated funtion

```
g[x_,y_]=x[[;; 2, ;; 2]]+expensiveFunction[y]
```

where I would like the `g[x]`part to be evaluated delayed and the `g[y]` part evaluated at the time of definition.

Ultimately, I would even like Mathematica to recognize that by `x[[;; 2, ;; 2]]` I have a 2x2 matrix and further functions of that 2x2 matrix are already evaluated without knowing the values there (e.g. determinant or trace):

```
h[x_,y_]=expensiveFunction1[x[[;; 2, ;; 2]]]+expensiveFunction2[y]
```

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to get rid of delayed evaluation?  I think delayed evaluation is *exactly* what you need, i.e. just use `f[x_] := x[[;; 2, ;; 2]];`

Comment: for this simple function, yes. But let's assume I have multiple arguments and for the sake of speed I would like to have the evaluation already performed for the other arguments.
Ideally, I would like to process even the matrix elements, for example getting the determinant or trace already (immediately evaluated). So I guess this is all possible when using the pure function notation. But for readability it might be easier to use speaking variable names.

[Note, `SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]; f[x_] = x[[;; 2, ;; 2]];` (as you just suggested before editing) gives the same error.]

Comment: Sorry about the totally misguided suggestion; my gut reaction before reading more carefully was that that would help.  I still do not understand what you are asking however.  You start by showing a memoizing construct which *sounds* like what you are saying you want, but then apparently you don't want it.  Please edit your question to include a *complete example* that illustrates how `f[x_] := f[x] = x[[;; 2, ;; 2]];` does not do what you want.

Comment: yes I realized that, sorry! Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is similarity to a question that came up yesterday; you might take a look:

- [Puzzled regarding avoiding evaluations and using results of computations as functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137913/121)

If we assume that `expensiveFunction` works symbolically on a single parameter the code you wrote already works as-is despite the warning message from `Part`:

```
expensiveFunction = Total[#^Range[5]] &;

g[x_, y_] = x[[;; 2, ;; 2]] + expensiveFunction[y];

?g
```

> ```
> g[x_, y_] = y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + y^5 + x[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]]
> ```

If you just want to avoid that message you have several options including:

1. `Quiet[g[x_, y_] = . . . , Part::take]`
2. `Block[{Part}, g[x_, y_] = . . . ]`
3. [Prevent Part[] from trying to extract parts of symbolic expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645/121)

The first is actually the one I recommend.  It really is just a *warning* message in this case, not an error.  `Block` is handy but it disables `Part` *throughout* the evaluation which can potentially break code in unexpected ways.  The last method is OK but really you just create another layer of evaluation that is unnecessary.

Related:

- [About nonstandard evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135801/121)
- [how to manipulate pattern-matched lists for replacements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136522/121)

Comment: this is really helpful, also the other questions you mentioned sound like problems that are likely to occur for me very soon, too. Will dive into them next week when I have a bit more time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @riddleculous Glad I could help. :-)